# Curved shape layout in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

I want know, how to create this curved radius style layout with left side height is greater than right side height.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="150dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />

<solid android:color="@color/red/>
```

But I want to know how to achieve this height: left side is higher than right side.

Comment: that could just be an image

Comment: i want know how can i achieve this corner by using shape drawable

Comment: You wouldn't use a shape drawable, shape is really limited.  You'd use an image or a vector drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used vector image as background to get this shape

SignIn page Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/diagonal_rect_size_pos"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sixitLogoImageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sixit_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sixit_logo_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/sixit_logo_white"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_padding"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

background.xml

```
   <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="360.002dp"
    android:height="280.806dp"
    android:viewportWidth="360.002"
    android:viewportHeight="280.806">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0.002,0h359.969v179.557a18.379,18.379 0,0 1,-11.213 17.919c-4.179,4.213 -336.377,82.7 -339.615,82.745s-9.274,4.732 -9.142,-13.251c0.133,0.001 0.001,-266.97 0.001,-266.97z"
      android:fillColor="#161616"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library for such thing. [DiagonalLayout by Florent37](https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout)

Here is a quick sample of it.

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        diagonal:diagonal_angle="10"
        diagonal:diagonal_position="left / right / top / bottom"
        diagonal:diagonal_direction="left / right"
        android:elevation="10dp">

    <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

</com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: it is possible to add radius on corners

Comment: You can use the library files if you want to modify them. It is open source.